# How to show $\mathsf{tr}(\nabla X)=\sum_{i=1}^n g(\nabla_{\partial_i}X,\partial_i)$ in a normal coordinate chart $(x^i)$ on $(M^{(n)},g)$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on a Riemannian $n$-manifold $(M,g)$. According to Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds*, the **total covariant derivative** $\nabla X$ of $X$ is a smooth $(1,1)$-tensor field on $M$. By applying trace(contraction) to the resulting field pointwise, we obtain a smooth function $\mathsf{tr}(\nabla X)$ on $M$, which is equal to
$$\sum_{i=1}^n g(\nabla_{\partial_i}X,\partial_i)\tag{$*$}$$
in a **normal coordinate chart** $(x^i)$ based on an online source. This equality is mysterious to me, and I would like to know its origin.

I know some good properties of normal coordinates. For example, the Christoffel symbols in these coordinates vanish at the center of the chart, and taking the first partial derivatives of $g_{ij}$ at the center yields nullity. But I still fail to conjure expression $(*)$ out of these properties.

Here's how I began with an understanding of $\mathsf{tr}(\nabla X)$ in local coordinates. If we denote the components of $\nabla X$ in $(x^i)$ by ${X^i}_{;j}$ writing $X=X^i\partial_i$, then $\nabla X$ can be expressed as
$${X^i}_{;j}\partial_i\otimes dx^j$$
with
$${X^i}_{;j}=\partial_j X^i+X^k\Gamma_{jk}^i.$$
What should I do next in order for the smooth function $\mathsf{tr}(\nabla X)$?

Thank you.

**Update:** Thanks to @Didier, I found the title of my question to be *misleading*. It is not true for the entire normal neighborhood, but I will leave it be, for those who may need it.

Comment: This is not true unless $\partial_i$'s form an orthonormal basis. What is true however is that if $A$ is an endomorphism of the inner product space $(E,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$, then $\mathrm{trace}(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle Ae_i,e_i\rangle$ for $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ an orthonormal basis of $E$.

Comment: Thank you, but this is indeed the case because $(x^i)$ are normal coordinates.

Comment: In normal coordinates, this is true at the center of the chart but not everywhere. In any case, this is just basic linear algebra (see my edited comment above)

Comment: @Didier Thank you. Allow me some time for the case of Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: @Didier With the inner product $g_p$ on $T_p M$, we can write $$\mathsf{tr}((\nabla X)_p)=\sum_{i=1}^n g_p\left((\nabla X)_p\partial_i|_p,\partial_i|_p\right),$$ which is still different from the desired result. If it is convenient to you, I wonder why $$(\nabla X)_p\partial_i|_p=(\nabla_{\partial_i}X)_p.$$ Do I need any isomorphism to change the $(1,1)$-tensor $(\nabla X)_p$ into a linear operator on $T_p M$? Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by $(\nabla X) \partial_i$? The (1,1) tensor $\nabla X$ acts by $Y \mapsto \nabla_YX$!

Comment: @Didier In Lee's book, the total covariant derivative $\nabla X$ is a $(1,1)$-tensor field. After injecting a point $p\in M$ into this field, we obtain a $(1,1)$-tensor $(\nabla X)_p$. This tensor cannot act on the tangent vector $\partial_i|_p$ unless it is identified with a linear operator on the tangent space $T_p M$(an endomorphism of $T_p M$). This is what I think the tangent vector $(\nabla X)_p\partial_i|_p$ is all about. That identification can be found on page 394.

Comment: It is universally admitted that $(1,1)$ tensors and fields of endomorphisms are basically the same. And the definition of the $(1,1)$ tensor $\nabla X$ is precisely $Y \mapsto \nabla_YX$. You may write it $(\nabla X) Y$ if you want, or $(DX)Y$ or anything, but still its values are given by the evaluation of the covariant derivative of $X$ in the considered direction

Comment: @Didier Thank you, but I still don't know what you're saying. From the beginning to the end, I have been following the definition of $\nabla X$ depicted in Proposition 4.17, which says that $\nabla X$ acts on one covector field $\omega$ and one vector field $Y$ to give $(\nabla_Y X)\omega$. This is probably why I'm not with you all the time. Let me think about it. Chances are that you are perfectly right.

Answer (score 3):

For contracting (taking trace) we must have one upper index and one lower index then setting them equal and summing over this index. (Something similar to matrices for $[a_{ij}]$ we must set $i=j$ then sum all diagonal entries! Note that in the case of matrices the metric is Euclidean metric and raising or lowering indices will not affect on the result.)

In the case of your problem, luckily we have a lower and an upper index. So just set them equal and sum over $i=1,...,n$. Why do we do this? we just need the coefficients ${X^j}_{;j}$  without term $\partial_i\otimes dx^j$. So one good technique is that by evaluating ${X^i}_{;j}\partial_i\otimes dx^j$ at $\partial_j$ it gives vector field ${X^i}_{;j}\partial_i$ then inner producting with $\partial_j$ will give what we want. i.e. ${X^j}_{;j}$. Is that clear?

Comment: (just to emphasis my remark on "this is just true at the center of the normal coordinates" in the comment section:) The inner product with $\partial_j$ gives, in full generality, $g(\nabla_{\partial_j}X,\partial_j)= \sum_{i=1}^n X^i_{;j}g(\partial_i,\partial_j)$. If the coordinates are normal, then at the center of the chart $p\in M$, $g(\partial_i|_p,\partial_j|_p) = \delta_{ij}$, from which we get the desired quantity